# using selenium to automate client allowing use of camera

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, getusermedia

I am making a WebRTC application and the allow permission to use camera pops up. I know there is no way to remove that but is there a way to automate the clicking of the allow button using selenium on the client's side? because the 90% of the clients are not clicking the allow button, even though we put an instruction to click the allow button and that it is safe to click it but still they are not clicking it and some clicked deny.

Currently my only solution is by letting the client download a c# application and all it does is restart the browser with --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream, but I think its not a good idea. So if there is a way to automate the clicking of allow button please tell me. Thanks guys, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out http://testrtc.com/

They use Selenium internally, with a focus on testing WebRTC services. They make sure the allow button gets pressed (=overridden) and replace the camera and microphone with virtual devices and media files of your choosing.

Comment: Hello Tsahi, thanks for replying.. Can you teach me on how to use testrtc?